# Can´t deploy a NodeJS app on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, amazon-web-services

I've done a NodeJS app that runs flawlessly in my local machine. I've tried to deploy into Heroku, but when I curl it, it says "Application error".

This is my package.js:

```
{
    "name": "maybe",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "description": "desc",
    "repository": "local heroku",
    "author": "me",
    "engines": {
        "node": "0.8.x",
        "npm": "1.1.x"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "express": "3.0.0rc2",
        "request": "2.9.202",
        "jade": "~0.27.2",
        "path": "~0.4.9",
        "aws-sdk": "2.0.23",
        "knox": "~0.3.1"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "web.js"
    }
}
```

As you can see, I use aws-sdk yo upload a file to S3.

If I perform "heroku run bash", I can "node server.js" and It seems to run correctly.

My port is "port = process.env.PORT || 3000;", being my env variable also PORT=3000.

So, any idea about whats going wrong????

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I've finally solved this issue by performing a full app reset & clean. So I don´t really know what was failing, but my app is now working :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you defined a Procfile so that Heroku knows which file to run?

See here - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#define-a-procfile

Comment: Your answer is really useful, however my Procfile is alright. Thanks for your answer anyway. I believe somebody may find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can usually find out why things aren't working by inspecting the Heroku logs. If you open your terminal and run:

```
heroku ps:restart; heroku logs --tail
```

That will restart your app, and open your logs files so you can see what error messages Heroku is giving you. This way you can see what the issue is and fix it quickly =)

Comment: Although I was already checking the logs this way, I also think your answer may help other people.